# Can someone explain this While loop in a linked list to me?

Tags: c++, data-structures, while-loop, linked-list

I'm confused with this while loop statement while creating a linked list:  `while(curr->next != NULL)` But `curr->next` will always be `NULL` since we never initialized `curr->next` to point to anything, so that while loop should never run!

Can someone explain this, please??  The code snippet is as follows:

```
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        curr = head;
        while(curr->next != NULL)
        {
            curr = curr->next;
        }

        curr->next = n;
    }
```

The complete code is shown below:

```
void AddNode(int addData)
{
    nodePtr n = new node;
    n->next = NULL;
    n->data = addData;

    if (head != NULL)
    {
        curr = head;
        while(curr->next != NULL)
        {
            curr = curr->next;
        }

        curr->next = n;
    }
    else
    {
        head = n;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but 'curr' is changed in the loop

Comment: Yes it's changed, but doesn't the while loop only run if the statement in the while loop is true? @pm100

Comment: `curr = head;` do youn know what this means?

Comment: @ItagakiFumihiko, ```curr = head```, yes I think I know what it means but I don't know what you're referring to can you be more specific?

Comment: The code iterates over the linked list to find the last node. It follows the next pointer of each node, starting at the head of the linked list, until there is no next node (curr->next is NULL). It's a precursor to appending a new node to the end of the linked list. If there is only a head node then the while loop is not entered, but otherwise it is.

Comment: The line `curr->next = n` sets the `next` pointer, so as long as you've added more than one node to the list then `curr->next` will in fact have a non-NULL value at least once.

Comment: *"since we never initialized curr->next"* - what do you think the lines `n->next = NULL;` and `curr->next = n;` did on the prior invokes of `AddNode` that placed the node now pointed to by `curr` ? I submit you need to revisit how pointers work. It's not terribly complicated, and *extremely* important. You'd be amazed how much drawing boxes and arrows on a whiteboard will help clarify this.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for the suggestions and reply to the answer, it's clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curr->next` is null only on the second call to `AddNode`. The first call to `AddNode` we go to the `head = n;` branch. On the second call, `curr->next` will be null and the `while` loop doesn't execute at all. But notice what happens after that, at the end of that second call. The `curr->next = n;` makes `curr->next` no longer null, appending `n` to this linked list. By the third call, `curr->next` is not null. The `while` loop iterates through the nodes with `curr = curr->next` until `curr->next` is null again (last node), then appends to that last node via `curr->next = n;`.

Answer (score 0):

It is checking it's current position and updating it every time until it reach end of a linked list
Example:

```
[1->[address of 2 ] ,2->[address of 3 ],3->[address of 4 ],4->[address of 5 ],5->[NULL ]]
current = 1;

while loop start check the next of current if its not null update current value 
current =2
current =3
current=4
current=5
when it reach last element of linked list current next is now null it will stop.
outside of while loop add new element at the end of linked list
```